# CipherLAB - Barcode scanner event - xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode

Hello I get CipherLap 'smartphone' with laser barcode scanner. This scanner is working like keyboard. My goal is to write simple app to read example data and valid it. This what I have done is:

Made an `<Entry />` and hide it.
On start view I `Focus()` entry, click scan and `TextChanged` event write it to my `<Label />`

But after all its not rly smart and my question is. Is in xamarin.form any better way do get example data without using and hiding `<Entry />` ?
ps. It also pop keyboard on screen and its also a bit annoying.

Comment: Have you tried using [ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms](https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile.forms)? This is a component that helps you read bar codes. I do not understand your question very well, can you leave a snippet of code?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these rugged smartphones, that includes a barcode scanner, make available some sort of SDK to integrate barcode scanning capability in third-party applications.
I don't have much experience with CipherLab (I work for Zebra Technologies and we've [different SDKs available including one for Xamarin](https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/xamarin)).
Looking on [Cipherlab website](https://www.cipherlab.com/s/2/product-c56152/Kalipso-Mobile-Application-Generator.html) I've not been able to find any SDK but you should contact the company that sold you the device.

Comment: ouch, i didn't know about that there should be sdk. I will talk to my co-workers then, Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is late but it may help others.

A Xamarin component/plugin/whatever they call it now would need to be implemented. Cipherlab mentioned plans for this but I don't know what happened.

You could look at my react native plugin to help you get started.

https://github.com/mribbons/react-native-cipherlab-scanner

You can also contact your supplier to get a copy of the sample native application.

It would be great if Cipherlab made this available publicly.